# cmdArgs bash completion

Tags: haskell, autocomplete, bash-completion

The [cmdArgs package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.3) for Haskell provide command option parsing.

based on this page from the docs http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs-Explicit.html#g:4 and its source http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/src/System-Console-CmdArgs-Explicit-Complete.html#Complete

It seem able to support bash completion, but I was not able to made it  work with the Implicit version of the parser. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cmdargs/0.10.3/doc/html/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html

Does any one have any example of doing this?

Edit added a better example

if I have the program

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import System.Console.CmdArgs

data Sample = Sample {hello :: String}
              deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

sample = Sample{hello = def}

main = print =<< cmdArgs sample
```

with parses the following options

```
The sample program

sample [OPTIONS]

Common flags:
  -h --hello=ITEM
  -? --help        Display help message
  -V --version     Print version information
```

how do use the bash completion feature of cmdArgs?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for? The package docs you linked to have a short example in them.

Comment: I added some more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the bash completion, compile the above program as `sample`, place `sample` on your `$PATH` then run:

```
sample --help=bash > sample.comp
source sample.comp
```

You can now type in `sample --ver`, press tab, and it will complete to `sample --version`.

There are a couple of infelicities in the completion, in particular the program must be on your `$PATH` and if you are on Windows you need to run `sample.comp` through `dos2unix`. It is also entirely undocumented, which sHould be fixed by the package author.