# Does shake support bash completion?

Tags: bash, haskell, autocomplete, shake-build-system

I am learning to use [shake](http://shakebuild.com/) to replace Makefile and wonder if `shake` have `bash-completion` support.

For example, a simple (do nothing) `Makefile`

```
all :

clean:
```

would show a tab completion target as

```
$ make <TAB>                                           
all    clean
```

but there is no `target-completion` when using `./build <TAB>` complied from this `build.hs`

```
import Development.Shake

main :: IO ()
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="_build"} $ do
    phony "all" $ return ()

    phony "clean" $ do
      putNormal "Cleaning files in _build"
      removeFilesAfter "_build" ["//*"]
```

I am expect something similar to [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/shell_autocompletion/#for-bash-users) or Python's [argcomplete](https://argcomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: As far as I know *autocompletion* is *not* specific to a program: the operating system has a set of rules to do autocompletion. So you cannot do this on a "program level" so to speak, since the OS cannot derive this from the program binary.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, however it's relatively easy (albeit hackish) to tell the OS to _ask the program for completions_. For instance `cabal` uses this route, via some command-line flag (forgot which, it's not really documented).

Comment: I have no idea what command parsing library used in shake, but there is [cmdArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863284/cmdargs-bash-completion) that seem to have bash-completion

Comment: as both shake and cmdArgs are written in haskell, I'd have said that @ndmitchell would have used it, but checking the documentation, shake does not depend on cmdArgsr

Comment: It works for `bash` because you have something defined for `make` that says to look for strings matching `^.*:` in the Makefile when completing the first argument for `make`. You would need to write (or find) a similar set of definitions for `shake` (or more specifically, `build`).

Answer (score 0):

Not currently, but there's a ticket to add it: https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/601